# Deleting duplicates in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

i'm fairly new to VBA and could do with a bit of help. I've looked online and i've found a few bits of code but have been unable to amend to my needs.

I'm trying to create a macro that will enable me to see if their are any duplicate text between column A and B and if the text in column A matches Column B then we will need to delete the entire row. The columns are on the same sheet

I am trying to create a loop that will do this. I must also point out that the length of the list does increase every week

I would appreciate any help

Thank you

Comment: Does it need to be VBA? You could simply use the COUNTIF function to find duplicates, returning more than 1 for any duplicated entries. Do you want to delete both lines or only one (in the case of 2 rows, 1 duplicate) ?

Comment: Yes unfortunately it has to be done in vba as it is part of a much larger Macro. If the data matches on column a and B i would prefer to delete entire column using EntireRow.Delete

Comment: If you're using VBA, then the `Scripting.Dictionary` class should help you immensely.  I'd recommend you read up on it, try your hand at some code, and then post your code if you run into specific issues

Answer (score 0):

Hi try in your code VBA:

```
Sub DeleteRowWithContents()
'========================================================================
' DELETES ALL ROWS FROM A2 DOWNWARDS WITH THE WORDs "Record Only" IN COLUMN D
'========================================================================
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "D").Value) = "Record Only" Then
    'Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.ClearContents ' USE THIS TO CLEAR CONTENTS BUT NOT DELETE ROW
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

you can update this code for your problem! 
I use this when i need deletes all rows from a2 downwards with the words "record only" in column d.

Comment: Thanks rdn87,  If the words are dynamic and change everytime. how would we get round this issue?

Comment: @MCharm88 I would try replacing all instances of `"D"` with `"B"` and then also change `"Record Only"` to be `Cells(i,"A").Value`.  This would allow the code to get the last used row in column B and then compare column B entries against column A entries before deletion.

Comment: @NinjaLlama , Thank you for you response, I seem to have a mismatch error for line "If (Cells(i, "B").Value) = Cells(i, "A").Value Then". Is there another way round this

Comment: @MCharm88 What types of data do you have in those columns?

Comment: @NinjaLlama I have email addresses so text, so would this need to be  done as a dim then data type string?

Comment: @MCharm88 I have just tested with email addresses as text and cannot reproduce your error.  I am not sure what is happening.

Comment: @NinjaLlama, Thank you for your help, i can't see why it is producing the error but you've help me alot thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
Sub DeleteRowWithContents()
    Dim ColumnAValue As String
    Dim ColumnBValue As String
    Dim xlWB As Worksheet

    Set xlWB = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'If it isn't the active sheet use second row:
    'Set xlWB = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NameOfSheet") 'Change to the name of your sheet

    For i = 1 To EOF  'This goes through the whole document to the last row automatically, EOF means "End Of File"
        ColumnAValue = xlWB.Cells(i, 1).Value 'row i, column "a"
        ColumnBValue = xlWB.Cells(i, 2).Value 'row i, column "b"
        If (ColumnAValue = ColumnBValue) Then
            xlWB.Range(ColumnAValue).Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Delete 'NOTE!!
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

NOTE: I'm not too sure if this works, can't test it right now. IF it doesn't, try this instead:

```
EntireRow.Select
Selection.Delete
```